# Convert JSON data column to specific array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I want to convert my json to array

```
var data = {1:{id: '2014-924', name: 'abc'},2:{id: '2014-925', name: 'xyz'}};

var result = ['2014-924','2014-925'];`outout`
```

Answer (score 1):

The value you want in your result array is present in the values for `id` in your object. You can loop through the values of the object to get the 'id'.

Use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get an array of values of your object. Then loop through the array to collect the id.

Here is an example using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var data = {1:{id: '2014-924', name: 'abc'},2:{id: '2014-925', name: 'xyz'}};


const result = Object.values(data).map(x => x.id)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your data should be in the following format

```
var data = '{"data": [{"id": "2014-924", "name": "abc"}, {"id": "2014-924", "name": "abc"}]}'
```

The you can deserialise the json using JSON.parse();

```
var resultObject = JSON.parse(data);
```

And to create the result array:

```
var result = [resultObject.data[0].id, resultObject.data[1]];
```

Comment: OP *probably* has a javascript object that they've confused with JSON.   It doesn't look like it starts as an array.